# US naturalization – Is there a gov. agency to contact to retrieve list of all times traveled outside of the US?

Tags: usa, paperwork

I'm reading the documentation describing the process of becoming a citizen in the United States, and they want a document describing all the times one has traveled outside of the country.

If one resided as a permanent resident in the USA for 20 years and was young when they first immigrated, how would one retrieve all these instances of travel?

Is there a government entity that would have a record of travel that can be contacted?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the government would share such records (I kind of doubt it), but surely the citizenship paperwork will also want to know where you went, and the US almost certainly doesn't know that for sure; when you cross a border outside the US, AFAIK there's no way for the US to be notified.

Comment: Even if all my travels were always from us to somewhere, and that same somewhere back to us. Every time.

Comment: Ok, then I suppose in principle it's possible.  I don't have any idea who to ask, though.

Comment: Assuming you only used a handful of airlines, and assuming you're a member of their frequent flyer programs, you could try asking them for the list of flights you credited to your frequent flyer program account over the years?

Comment: There's certainly no government agency to give you this info, because the government doesn't have all that info.  In many international airports in the US, when you leave the country, nobody checks your passport except the airline - and they don't need to pass the info to the US government unless your name flags up against some checking/blacklist system (in which case you wouldn't fly anyway).

Comment: @AleksG I think they do have to pass the info. My understanding is that the list is not shared with the airlines. It goes the other way around and the government does the matching. But I don't know precisely what information is retained, for how long, since when such data is collected and who can have access to them.

Comment: I remember as a child passing the border and the guard simply lazily looking at the passport and waving us in. I can back track some dates using my debit card but for the most part any time before 2006 I'm completely at the mercy of my memory and maybe perhaps my pictures would be the last remaining alternatives.

Comment: I'm going to call the USCIS help number on monday and see what they recommend.

Answer (score 2):

There are many agencies in the US that track immigration records, listed on [the USCIS website](http://www.uscis.gov/about-us/freedom-information-and-privacy-act-foia/how-file-foia-privacy-act-request/submitting-foia-requests). Your best bet seems to be requesting your Entry and Exit records from the CBP (see http://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia/faq-foia). Note that according to the first link I provided, "*CBP does not have records on the entry and exit of persons arriving or departing the U.S. before 1982*", but if you're interested in only 20 years it should be enough.

Another relevant link: http://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia/records